# Is "when" grammatically necessary in "at the same time as when?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, as, redundancy

> "The militia was formed when demons and monsters appeared on the
>   island, at the same time **as when** the Stormwall formed."

Should "when" be left out in this sentence because there is semantically a overlap between "as" and "when"? Or Could "When" be put after "as" of the phrase "at the same time as" in order to intensify the moment? If so, what is "when" considered as in the grammar aspect?

Comment: Personally, I don't think "as when" is necessary at all. "at the same time the Stormwall formed." is fine... though, did the Stormwall form itself or was it built by someone? If the latter is the case, you should probably say "was formed".

Comment: I am having the same opinion as @Catija. But if you use **as**, that **when** is compulsory. The construction is **same ...as...**.

Comment: @Man_From_India I think it's debatable whether "when" is required if you use "as". As a native AmE speaker, I think all three options are fine, grammatically. "As when" just feels a bit overly wordy.

Comment: @Catija You are right. Now that you mentioned it, I reconsidered what I had earlier said. And I think you are right. **when** is not compulsory even when there is **as**. Thanks :-)

Comment: Side note to Catija's reply. You definitely want "was" after Stormwall, but it is good practice to not repeat the same word in a sentence if possible. Instead of using "formed" a second time, find a synonym such as "founded", "organized", or "established."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My feeling about it is that *when* isn't necessary, and at least a little bit questionable.

1. The militia was formed at the same time as when the Stormwall formed
2. The militia was formed at the same time as the Stormwall formed
3. The militia was formed at the same time as the Stormwall
4. The militia was formed when the Stormwall formed

Obviously **4** is ungrammatical without when, but **2** and **3** are just as fine as **1**.

Contrary to what the comments say, you don't need *was* after *the Stormwall (formed)*, because it's implied by the syntax. In other words, readers will read *the Stormwall **was** (formed)* even if it's not there. Indeed, you can use either or both, except for **5** below. It seems... at least a little infelicitous, if not ungrammatical.

5. ?The militia was formed at the same time as when the Stormwall was
6. The militia was formed at the same time the Stormwall was
7. The militia was formed when the Stormwall was